# How to select an element from a 2d array in a file in Linux shell

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting and what I need is to read from a file that contains a 2d array. Assume there is a file named test.dat which contains values as:

```
- Paris         London     Lisbon
- Manchester    Nurnberg   Istanbul
- Stockholm     Kopenhag   Berlin
```

What is the easiest way to select an element from this table in linux bash scripts? For example, the user inputs -r 2 -c 2 test.dat that implies to selecting the element at row[2] and column[2] (Nurnberg).

I have seen the read command and googled but most of the examples were about 1d array.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612595/how-to-use-schell-script-to-read-element-from-a-file-do-some-calculation-and-wr) one looks familiar but could not understand it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is great for this:

```
$ awk 'NR==row{print $col}' row=2 col=2 file
Nurnberg
```

- `NR==row{}` means: on number of record number `row`, do `{}` Number of record normally is the number of line.
- `{print $col}` means: print the field number `col`.
- `row=2 col=2` is giving both parameters to `awk`.

---

#### Update

> One more little question: How can I transform this into a sh file so
>   that when I enter -r 2 -c 2 test.dat into prompt, I get to run the
>   script so that it reads from the file and echoes the output? – 
>   iso_9001_.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
row=$2
col=$3

awk 'NR==row{print $col}' row=$row col=$col $file
```

And you execute like:

```
./script a 3 2
Kopenhag
```

Comment: Great! I was suspecting awt would work :) Thank you very much

Comment: `awk` is sooooo powerful for this kind of things :) Glad it worked to you!

Comment: One more little question: How can I transform this into a sh file so that when I enter  `-r 2 -c 2 test.dat` into prompt, I get to run the script so that it reads from the file and echoes the output?

Comment: You are really fast and have been very helpful  :)  thank you very much

Comment: Today, I have successfully managed to write the code as you suggested. So, thanks again. What I now lack is, I can manage to run the code as `./tablooku.sh tablom.dat 2 2` but when I try to parameterize "2 2" part as `./tablooku.sh tablom.dat -r 2 -c 2` I get my error message that says "Error: -rth row and -cth column does not exist". How can I parameterize the command?

Comment: Well, you do not have to indicate `-r 2 -c 2`. Instead, just `2 2`, like I comment in the last part of my answer: `./tablooku.sh tablom.dat 2 2` would be enough.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is enough. Besides I managed to run the code as `./tablooku.sh tablom.dat 2 2` through your instructions. But what I am  curious is how to parameterize the input. Is there a simple way?

Comment: Ah, I see. Then you may consider using `getopts`. You can check http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial and also questions like http://stackoverflow.com/q/402377/1983854

Comment: @fedroqui Great.! :) Thanks, I will check these links now.